# C# sending huge and small data buffers by socket and TCP

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I want to send huge buffers (from 100MB to 1GB) of data by TCP. I solved it by dividing buffer to smaller (approximately 1MB buffers) and sending by socket.send(). Each call of socket.send() method, send part of data (smaller buffer) packed in specific structure: [start byte(1B), Timestamp(4B), Command(4B), Length of data(4B), Data to send(?B), CRC(1B), End byte(1B)]. Everything works fine, when only one huge buffer is sent by specific port. But when I try to send in the same time buffer with another data (very small, e.g. 20 bytes) using the same TCP port, then TCP mixed data in buffers and it's not possible to decode buffer any more. 'Start byte' and 'end byte' in the buffer are not useful to find start and end of the buffer, because it's probable that these bytes appear in data.

**EDIT:** Issue does not affect the order or IDs between packages but bytes in the packages. At the beginning everything works fine and each buffer is decoded properly. After a while it is not possible to decode buffer, because it contains incorrect data. It looks like bytes in the buffer were moved or changed. Fields at the beginning of the buffer (timestamp, command, length) contain impossible values. So when I want to get length of sent data, I get e.g. value like -1534501133 instead of 1048556 (1048556 is a correct maximum size of the sent data in one package). It happens randomly but it is always connected with the moment when smaller independent buffer is sent. The additional information is, that the smaller buffers are sent repetitively using timers and the problem happens in random moments. Sometimes it is even possible to send whole data (e.g. 300 MB) without problem but it happens very rarely.

I hope, I described it clearly enough.

Do you have any suggestions how to avoid this problem?

Comment: *'Start byte' and 'end byte' in the buffer are not useful to find start and end of the buffer, because it's probable that these bytes appear in data.* So what? You encoded the length in there. It's not clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Tag your data with a unique id so you know what data relates to what message. Also, separate the packet header from the packet payload.

So, your first request would be [ID][PACKETTYPE][TIME][COMMAND][LENGTH][CRC]

Second would be [ID][PACKETTYPE][DATA]

You can then match up the IDs with the types of packet. So packet type would be 'HEADER' or 'PAYLOAD', the header would contain the meta data for the payload allowing you to make sure that it doesnt get mixed up with other data.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. I added some information to my post to explain it a little bit more.